# According to NEC 210.52 can this receptacle be counted as part of the required outlets in a dwelling?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Under NEC code artcile 210.52 Dwelling Unit Receptacle Outlets

...The receptacles required by this section shall be in addition to any receptacle that is:

(1) Part of a luminaire or appliance, or

(2) Controlled by a wall switch in accordance with 210.70( A) (1), Exception No. 1, or

(3) Located within cabinets or cupboards, or

(4) **Located more than 1.7 m (5 ½ ft) above the floor**

So my question is if I have a half switched outlet at 60" that is behind a painting, is that counted as part of the required outlets in a dwelling since it is less than 5 1/2 ft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be counted as a required receptacle since it does meet the letter of the code.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. Speedy is right, But....

If you apply 210.52(A)(1)

> (1) Spacing. Receptacles shall be installed such that no point measured horizontally along the floor line of any wall space is more than 1.8 m (6 ft) from a receptacle outlet.

And a little trigonometry....then your receptacle doesn't cover much of the floor line since it is 5' AFF already.

I will leave the rest of the maths up to you.

Comment: I would think the key directive here is "horizontally" which *should* be any permanent hot outlet under 5' 6", no?

Comment: Upon further investigation it would seem the majority interpretation supports you Kris. I still feel a receptacle mounted that high is of little utility to items at the floor line, but the code does set the maximum height at 5'6" and yours and Speedy's interpretation of this section is the correct one.